# How can I import http.client module in PyCharm 2016.3 and Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, http.client

I would like to import http.client module in PyCharm 2016.3 (I am using Python 3.6). But, there is no module name "http.client" in the "add" section in "project interpreter" category. How can I import the module?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It is a built-in module in Python; you can import it directly:

```
>>> import http.client
>>> http.client
<module 'http.client' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py'>
```